# TEXT types truncating my data in SQL, Apache Ignite and unixODBC driver

Tags: php, sql, ignite, unixodbc

I wont to use Apache Ignite like a SQL server in my PHP application. To connect with Ignite I use unixODBC driver and standard PHP/PDO library.

I try to create table with TEXT type. TEXT data type is not supported
by ODBC driver but I can use types like: VARCHAR or LONGVARCHAR.

Problem is that every time my text is truncating to 64 characters. Why? Haw
Can I configure Apache Ignite / unixODBC to work with normal TEXT type?

I tested every text types in ODBC. I try to change ODBC configuration to add
in DSN options in my connection description like:

```
/etc/odbc.ini

[Apache Ignite]
description=Apache Ignite
driver=Apache Ignite
ADDRESS=127.0.0.1:10800
TextSize = 20971520
PacketSize = 20971520
```

Here is line from my application who create table:

```
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_md5 (id int PRIMARY KEY, userkey LONGVARCHAR, server LONGVARCHAR, tsession LONGVARCHAR, tpost LONGVARCHAR, tget LONGVARCHAR, adddate int)';
```

I think that problem is in unixODBC driver.

Thank you for all reply.

Answer (score 1):

This is an column meta issue of the ODBC driver. There is a ticket for this - [1].

[1] - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-7362

Comment: I know, I was asked for this in apache ignite users forum: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Apache-Ignite-amp-unixODBC-and-truncating-text-td19306.html